# grey transparent unclickable back screen

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to create a gray transparent background screen, on top of my original html page.
What I have done so far is to append a div (with jquery) to the body tag with this css style:

```
.spesificPropertiesDiv {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 6000;
text-align: center;
}
```

as I mentioned before I am appending a div with this class to the body.
Every works fine when I append it on large screen (24 inch) but when I am appending it on 16 inch display the gray screen div's  height is 100 px less than the body's height.
One more thing that I need to mention is that on large screen the page is fit on the screen where on the smaller screen a scroll-bar appears to make the page lower side of the page visible.
Why dose this happen? How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed it to:

```
.spesificPropertiesDiv{
    display: block;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 6000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and it works!!!!
Thank you all for the help

Comment: yes, the `*position: absolute` is for IE6 & 7, as it doesn't support `position: fixed`. It doesn't validate through w3c since `*` is a hack, but it should work fine if you don't care about validation. You could target it with a conditional stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try:

```
.spesificPropertiesDiv {
    position: fixed; *position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Additionally, is there any padding on this div? Is it a direct child of the `<body>` tag?:

```
<body>
    <div class="spesificPropertiesDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: is it look's like this: <body><div class="spesificPropertiesDiv"></div></body>

Comment: in addition, try setting html and body to height:100%. Just for the sake of testing/debugging. It shouldn't solve the problem since your element is fixed, but you never know.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error on this line: position: fixed; *position: absolute;